# Is there a list of components just for amp-story?

Tags: components, amp-html, amp-story

The main AMP site has a page that lists all of the components.
https://ampbyexample.com/#components

**Which of the following AMP components also work in `<amp-story>`?**

- amp-3d-gltf
- amp-access-laterpay
- amp-access
- amp-accordion
- amp-ad
- amp-analytics
- amp-anim
- amp-app-banner
- amp-audio
- amp-bind
- amp-bodymovin-animation
- amp-brid-player
- amp-brightcove
- amp-call-tracking
- amp-carousel
- amp-dailymotion
- amp-date-countdown
- amp-date-picker
- amp-dynamic-css-classes
- amp-experiment
- amp-facebook-comments
- amp-facebook-like
- amp-facebook-page
- amp-facebook
- amp-fit-text
- amp-font
- amp-form
- amp-fx-collection
- amp-fx-flying-carpet
- amp-geo
- amp-gfycat
- amp-gist
- amp-google-document-embed
- amp-google-vrview-image
- amp-hulu
- amp-iframe
- amp-ima-video
- amp-image-lightbox
- amp-image-slider
- amp-img
- amp-instagram
- amp-install-serviceworker
- amp-jwplayer
- amp-kaltura-player
- amp-lightbox-gallery
- amp-lightbox
- amp-list
- amp-live-list
- amp-mustache
- amp-next-page
- amp-o2-player
- amp-pinterest
- amp-pixel
- amp-reach-player
- amp-reddit amp-selector
- amp-sidebaramp-social-share
- amp-soundcloud
- amp-springboard-player
- amp-sticky-ad
- amp-timeago
- amp-twitter
- amp-user-notification
- amp-video
- amp-vimeo
- amp-vine
- amp-youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amp-story` has different components that are allowed as descendants of each component.  For a full list, see the [amp-story spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md), and see the "children" subsections for each of the components listed there.